# How can I add extra attribute in the 'Page Attribute' section in wp-admin for pages?

Tags: custom-field

I would like to add a select list in the `Page Attribute` box you see on the right side in the administration interface for pages.

Does anyone know if that is possible?

Or at least add a custom box below this box?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are no convenient hooks to add something to that box.

You could do one of two things.

**1. Add a new Meta Box**

You do this by hooking into the `add_meta_boxes` action and calling [`add_meta_box`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box).  You can specify a callback function in your call to add_meta_box.  That callback will take care of echoing out your select list.

```
<?php
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'wpse44966_add_meta_box' );
/**
 * Adds the meta box to the page screen
 */
function wpse44966_add_meta_box()
{
    add_meta_box(
        'wpse44966-meta-box', // id, used as the html id att
        __( 'WPSE 44966 Meta Box' ), // meta box title, like "Page Attributes"
        'wpse44966_meta_box_cb', // callback function, spits out the content
        'page', // post type or page. We'll add this to pages only
        'side', // context (where on the screen
        'low' // priority, where should this go in the context?
    );
}

/**
 * Callback function for our meta box.  Echos out the content
 */
function wpse44966_meta_box_cb( $post )
{
    // create your dropdown here
}
```

**2. Remove the Default Page attributes meta box, add your own version**

All the content on the post editting screen, with the exception of the main editor and title area, is a meta box.  You can remove them by calling [`remove_meta_box`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_meta_box), then replace them with your own.

So, first up, modify the add function above to include a remove meta box call.  Then you'll need to copy the `page_attributes_meta_box` function body from `wp-admin/includes/meta-boxes.php` and put your stuff below it.

```
<?php
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'wpse44966_add_meta_box' );
/**
 * Adds the meta box to the page screen
 */
function wpse44966_add_meta_box( $post_type )
{
    // remove the default
    remove_meta_box(
        'pageparentdiv',
        'page',
        'side'
    );

    // add our own
    add_meta_box(
        'wpse44966-meta-box',
        'page' == $post_type ? __('Page Attributes') : __('Attributes'),
        'wpse44966_meta_box_cb', 
        'page', 
        'side', 
        'low'
    );
}

/**
 * Callback function for our meta box.  Echos out the content
 */
function wpse44966_meta_box_cb( $post )
{
    // Copy the the `page_attributes_meta_box` function content here
    // add your drop down
}
```

Either way you do this, you'll need to hook into `save_post` to save the value of your field with `add_post_meta` and/or `update_post_meta`.

```
<?php
add_action( 'save_post', 'wpse44966_save_post' );
/**
 * Save our custom field value
 */
function wpse44966_save_post( $post_id )
{
    // check nonces, permissions here
    // save the data with update_post_meta
}
```

[This tutorial](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/plugins/how-to-create-custom-wordpress-writemeta-boxes/) might help you out.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer. I was hoping for some sort of a hook, but this will do just fine :)

Comment: excellent solution and good full answer - reference link fills in the gaps - thanks

Comment: As of WordPress 4.9 there _is_ an action hook `page_attributes_misc_attributes` that fires just after the Order field and just before the help text at the bottom of this meta box allowing expansion of the meta box instead of needing to replace it.  It passes a single argument, $post, the current post's object.

Answer (score 6):

Woohoo! As of WP 4.9.0, there is an action hook to add code to the Page Attributes meta box: `'page_attributes_misc_attributes'`. See the [Codex for reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/page_attributes_meta_box/).

Example:

```
function wpse44966_page_attributes( $post ) {

    wp_nonce_field( 'wpse44966_page_attributes_nonce', 'wpse44966_page_attributes_nonce' );
    ?>
    <p class="post-attributes-label-wrapper wpse44966-label-wrapper">
        <label class="wpse44966-label" for="wpse44966_option" style="font-weight: 600;"><?php _e( 'Option Label', 'textdomain' ); ?></label>
        <input id="wpse44966_option" name="wpse44966_option" type="checkbox" value="1" style="margin-left: 5px;"<?php if( isset( $post->wpse44966_option ) && $post->wpse44966_option ) echo ' checked="checked"'; ?>>
    </p>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'page_attributes_misc_attributes', 'wpse44966_page_attributes' );

function wpse44966_metabox_save_post( $post_id ) {
    if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;
    if( ! isset( $_POST['wpse44966_page_attributes_nonce'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['wpse44966_page_attributes_nonce'], 'wpse44966_page_attributes_nonce' ) ) return;
    if( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) return;
    $wpse44966_option = (int) ( isset( $_POST['wpse44966_option'] ) && $_POST['wpse44966_option'] );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'wpse44966_option', $wpse44966_option );
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'wpse44966_metabox_save_post' );
```

Comment: Reference moved to [https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/page_attributes_meta_box/](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/page_attributes_meta_box/)